# Looping over a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tuple of tuples:

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ('AFG', 'Afghanistan'),
    ('ALA', 'Aland Islands'),
    ('ALB', 'Albania'),
    ('DZA', 'Algeria'),
    ('ASM', 'American Samoa')
)
```

I tried:

`if country in COUNTRIES[0]` and didn't worked - I understand why;

Besides looping over the main tuple and check one by one, there is something similar to 'in' ?

Comment: because Python is case-sensitive. `COUNTRIES` is not the same as `Countries`. What error did you get?

Comment: What is your question? I do not understand the last sentence.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis , thanks, was just a typing mistake; I have a country str that correspond to the first element of the each tuple; my question is beside using for and going thru all of then,  and inside the loop using if, are any other more pythonic solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use chain in this case.

```
from itertools import chain

COUNTRIES = (
    ('AFG', 'Afghanistan'),
    ('ALA', 'Aland Islands'),
    ('ALB', 'Albania'),
    ('DZA', 'Algeria'),
    ('ASM', 'American Samoa')
)

if 'Albania' in chain.from_iterable(COUNTRIES):
    # do something
```

Comment: I need to check ALA, the 0, first element not second

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might want to use a dict. What about this?

```
COUNTRIES = {
    'AFG': 'Afghanistan',
    'ALA': 'Aland Islands',
    'ALB': 'Albania',
    'DZA': 'Algeria',
    'ASM': 'American Samoa'
}

country = "AFG"
if country in COUNTRIES:
    print "I found " + COUNTRIES[country]
```

Comment: you don't want `in COUNTRIES.keys()` in python 2...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure, but the question is tagged Python3?

Comment: okay, just do `in COUNTRIES` shorter and fast whatever python version

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, that's true. Fixed. Thanks. :)

Comment: Note that if you already have the tuple of tuples, you can just say `d = dict(COUNTRIES)` to create the `dict` shown here.